# CORS issue while attempting to make a POST request from my React

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, cors

I am facing a CORS issue while attempting to make a POST request from my React frontend to a PHP backend. The error message in the browser console is as follows:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/mcha-express/website/api/v1/book/:csrfToken' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

book.js:33 
        
POST http://localhost/mcha-express/website/api/v1/book/:csrfToken net::ERR_FAILED

book.js:62 Error submitting the form: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at handleSubmit (book.js:33:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:9288:1
```

Here are the relevant parts of my frontend and backend code:

```
// Frontend (book.js):

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Navbar from './navbar';
import Footer from './footer';

function Book(){
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = '';
  }, []);

  const [data, setData] = useState({
    full_name: '',
    email_address: '',
    contact_number: '',
    complete_address: '',
    details: ''
  });

  const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setData((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSubmitting(true);

    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost/mcha-express/website/api/v1/book/:csrfToken', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          csrfToken: 'a73f54b65f76467e9413a5c5fde2e32d1f3b4b82c7c0b0634a12bd6ca0b87dc2', 
          ...data,
        }),
      });

      const result = await response.json();

      // Handle the response accordingly
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log(result.message); // Successful response
        // Reset the form after successful submission if needed
        setData({
          full_name: '',
          email_address: '',
          contact_number: '',
          complete_address: '',
          details: '',
        });
      } else {
        console.error(result.error); // Error response
        // Handle error, display message, etc.
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting the form:', error);
    } finally {
      setSubmitting(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar/>
      {/* Book Section Start */}
      <section className='book'>
        <div className='book-bg'></div>
        <div className='container'>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h1>BOOK</h1>
            <p>Book now for effortless parcel delivery with us! Simply fill out the form, secure your slot, and leave the rest to us.</p>
            <div className='form-labels'>
              <div className={'response-message error'}>
                <span>Submitting</span>
              </div>
              <div className='labels'>
                <input
                  type='text'
                  placeholder='Full Name'
                  name='full_name'
                  value={data.full_name}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
                <input
                  type='email'
                  placeholder='Email Address'
                  name='email_address'
                  value={data.email_address}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className='labels'>
                <input
                  type='number'
                  placeholder='Contact Number'
                  name='contact_number'
                  value={data.contact_number}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
                <input
                  type='text'
                  placeholder='Complete Address'
                  name='complete_address'
                  value={data.complete_address}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className='label'>
                <textarea
                  rows='5'
                  placeholder='Please provide the details of your requirements...'
                  name='details'
                  value={data.details}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                ></textarea>
              </div>
              <div className='label'>
                <button type='submit'>
                  <span>Submit</span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>
      {/* Book Section End */}

      {/* Footer Section Start */}
      <Footer/>
      {/* Footer Section End */}
    </>
  );
}

export default Book;
```

#### Backend (index.php):

```
<?php

$request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$uri_parts = explode('/', $request_uri);
$endpoint = implode('/', array_slice($uri_parts, 2));

include 'api.php';

// POST book
if (strpos($endpoint, 'website/api/v1/book') !== false) {
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  $csrfToken = end($uri_parts);
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    post_book($csrfToken);
  } else {
    http_response_code(405);
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Invalid request method for this endpoint']);
  }
} 
?>
```

#### Backend (api.php):

```
<?php
// Security Headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, *");

include 'config.php';
session_start();

// Ito yung magkicreate ng csrf token
function generateCsrfToken() {
  if (!isset($_SESSION['csrf_token']) || !isset($_SESSION['csrf_token_expire']) || $_SESSION['csrf_token_expire'] < time()) {
    $_SESSION['csrf_token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
    $_SESSION['csrf_token_expire'] = time() + 300;
  }
  echo json_encode([
    'csrfToken' => $_SESSION['csrf_token'],
    'expiryDate' => $_SESSION['csrf_token_expire'],
  ]);
}

// Ito yung magbavalidate ng token
function validateCsrfToken($sentToken) {
  return isset($_SESSION['csrf_token']) && hash_equals($_SESSION['csrf_token'], $sentToken);
}

// Ichicheck kung yung csrf token ba is existing
function checkCsrfToken($sentCsrfToken) {
  if (!$sentCsrfToken || !validateCsrfToken($sentCsrfToken)) {
      http_response_code(403);
      echo json_encode(['error' => 'CSRF Token Validation Failed']);
      exit;
  }
}

// POST method ng pag iinsert ng book
function post_book($csrfToken) {
  global $pdo;

  // Defined variable
  $booking_id = 'BI-' . mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
  $full_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'full_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $email_address = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email_address', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  $contact_number = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'contact_number', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $complete_address = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'complete_address', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $details = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'details', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  // Ichicheck kung invalid ba yung csrf token
  if ($csrfToken !== $_SESSION['csrf_token']) {
      http_response_code(403);
      echo json_encode(['error' => 'CSRF Token Validation Failed']);
      exit;
  }

  // Kapag merong isang field yung missing
  if (!$csrfToken || !$full_name || !$email_address || !$contact_number || !$complete_address || !$details) {
      http_response_code(400);
      echo json_encode(['error' => 'Invalid input data']);
      exit;
  }

  // Taga check kung yung booking_id is nageexist naba
  $existingBookingQuery = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM book WHERE booking_id = ?");
  $existingBookingQuery->execute([$booking_id]);
  $existingBookingCount = $existingBookingQuery->fetchColumn();

  if ($existingBookingCount > 0) {
      http_response_code(400);
      echo json_encode(['error' => 'Booking ID already exists']);
      exit;
  }

  $sql = "INSERT INTO book (booking_id, full_name, email_address, contact_number, complete_address, details) 
          VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(1, $booking_id);
  $stmt->bindParam(2, $full_name);
  $stmt->bindParam(3, $email_address);
  $stmt->bindParam(4, $contact_number);
  $stmt->bindParam(5, $complete_address);
  $stmt->bindParam(6, $details);

  if ($stmt->execute()) {
      echo json_encode(['message' => 'Booking successfully submitted!']);
  } else {
      echo json_encode(['error' => '[Error] Failed to submit your booking.']);
  }

  $stmt->closeCursor();
}
?>
```

## Question Details:

- I have already set the necessary CORS headers in my PHP backend.
- The error specifically mentions an issue with the preflight OPTIONS request not having an HTTP ok status.

## What I've Tried:

- I have checked and confirmed that my CORS headers are correctly set.
- I have reviewed similar questions on Stack Overflow, but none of the solutions seem to resolve my issue.

## Request for Assistance:

How can I resolve this CORS issue. Is there something I might be missing in my setup?

Comment: Are you sure you're meant to have a literal `:csrfToken` in the URL path?

Comment: Supporting CORS means properly handling preflight `OPTIONS` requests. See the links at the top of your question for details and solutions